# Inlining calculations in a notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks

### Context

In $\LaTeX$, I can write something like:

```
  Thus, we have $x = \sqrt{2}$, ...

the $ ... $, as opposed to $$ ... $$, inline the LaTeX symbols.
```

Now, with *Mathematica*, I type a line of Input, I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it produces the answer on a different line of output. However, I would like to type something like this:

```
  Thus, we get $c^2 - c = 1$, and solving it, we get $N[solve[c^2 - c = 1, c]]$, ...
```

The idea is that mathematica evaluates the command, takes the output, and *inlines* it into the sentence, rather than have it as a separate line.

I have no idea how to do this. From what I've read, this sounds like "cells", but from goofing around, it's not clear how to make this work.

### Question:

How do I inline a mathematica expression, such that its output is displayed inline?

Comment: Hi user1311390! Would you mind individualizing your user name a bit? It makes this site a much cozier place.

Comment: Yeah! you could pick a personalized user id. Something  like `0931131resu`

Comment: @Sjoerd : done.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I feel better already. ;-)

Comment: I do have to admit, mathematica.stackexchange.com does seem like the friendliest of all stackexchanges I've used. Perhaps people who use mathematica tend to be smarter, and the community, as a result, doesn't become jaded and burnt out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the Evaluate in Place command, found in the Evaluation menu, do what you want or most of what you want? Starting with your example, correcting a couple of typos

```
Thus, we get $c^2 - c == 1$, and solving it, we get $N[Solve[c^2 - c == 1, c]]$, ...
```

select the portion

```
  N[Solve[c^2 - c == 1, c]]
```

with the mouse and either use the menu command Evaluate in Place or type Shift+Ctrl+Enter to get

```
Thus, we get $c^2 - c ==  1$, and solving it, we get $ {{c -> -0.6180339887498949`}, {c -> 
    1.618033988749895`}} $, ...
```

inline.

Comment: It's almost there. The following might be greedy. Is it possible that when I click on the evaluated result, it shows the original formula? A bit like cells in Microsoft Excel: when the cell is not in focus, show the result; when the cell is in focus, show original formula.

Comment: @user1311390 That would indeed be an interesting feature. Perhaps someone here will take up the challenge.

Comment: @term-rewritica I think that may require some Dynamic things and a self-defined function doing evaluation and formating together :)